# Showing annotations in outline view

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

I'm currently updating a test suite to use JUnit4 instead of JUnit3. It's all going well, there's no big problems, but in Eclipse it's now less easy to see the layout of a test.

What I mean is that with JUnit3 I could look in the Outline view to see the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods very easily. Now that I'm using `@Before`, `@After` and other annotations that information isn't so easy to find.

What I'd like is a way of seeing all the methods annotated with `@Before` or other annotations. A "find usages" for an annotation, if you like.

Am I being daft and the option is staring me in the face?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that such feature exists in standard Eclipse distribution. I just can recommend       you to continue using naming conventions for such methods (e.g. continue call them `setUp` and `tearDown`, so you will easily find them in outline view.

Comment: That was the conclusion I was coming to. Darn. Hopefully someone's going to come along and tell us both how it's done, but it might just be a good time for me to learn how to write plugins for Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

Not in the outline view, but `References > Workspace` (Ctrl-Shift-G) does work for annotations also and lists the hits as usual in the `Search` view. You only get the list for one type of annotation, and it is not as easy as a glance at the outline view. But then you still could stay with the naming scheme even in JUnit 4.

Comment: At least with the naming convention I could work my way through an overriding hierarchy of methods. Ah well, it'll undoubtedly appear in a future version.